# To modify the "title" in a Modal Dialog

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, message

i have create a very simply script:

```js
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p style="color:yellow; background:black">Font is yellow / Backround is black!</p>');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'My Headline');
```

to modify the "userinterface" is no problem - but how i can modify the "title"?

e.g. i will write the title "My Headline" like: "My ***Headline***" (Word headline in bold).

Comment: Modification of the title format isn't possible

Comment: Sch..... - thanks for the feedback

Comment: @tehhowch, is it possible to get it at least, like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73081219/11832197)? Thanks.

Comment: @onit that question is gone. I don't understand what you mean by "it", either - the title? the title's format?

Comment: Yes - My intention is to writhe only some words in e.g. bold.